# Can't find ToDictionary<TSource, TKey> in List<T>

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert `Collections.Generic.List<T>` to `Enumerable.ToDictionary<TSource, TKey>`.

I thought I could convert `List` to `Dictionary` by using `ToDictionary` method since `List` is `IEnumerable`. But visual studio complains that `ToDictionary` is not defined.

Here is my code.

```
Dictionary<int, SearchResult> dic = model.ResultItems.ToDictionary(x=>index++, x=>x);
```

and here is a definition of `ResultItems`

`public List<ResultsViewModel> ResultItems`

Can anyone give me how I can convert the `List` to `Dictionary`? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a reference to `System.Linq`?

Comment: If you leave an answer I will select it as an answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments, add a reference to `System.Linq`.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things you should check:

- You running .NET Framework 3.5 or higher;
- You have included `using System.Linq;` in your code file;
- The object you are calling it on implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

If so, you should be able to call [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549277%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).